# Подключение файла с константами в CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

Требуется подключить файл .php, где находятся константы, которые надо со временем изменить. Как его правильно подключить, чтобы можно было использовать константы во view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Храните константы в конфигах http://cidocs.ru/213e/libraries/config.html
Потом к ним можно обращаться через стандартные методы

```
$this->config->item('item name');
```

Comment: Благодарю за ответ!